# Converting a float with many decimal places to a float with one decimal place only

Tags: c

i want to know if there is a code that can convert float number like : 4.91820238 to a float with one decimal place only : 4.9 in C without using any libraries
P.S: I don't use print() function , I want to convert it and sotre its value ?

Comment: `convert`???? or represent? or print???

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: printf("%0.1f", var_flt);

Comment: @SouravGhosh  just convert i'm working with microcontroller no need to print.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`fmodf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) function in the standard `math.h` header.

[Then subtract the result from the original](https://ideone.com/aWD1gt).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float f = 4.9182;
    printf("%f", f - fmodf(f, 0.1));
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

I see from your comment that you are on a freestanding environment. So no standard library. But you can probably whip up you own function by consulting the example implementation on the reference site, and doing some inline assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply by 10 and divide by 10, do this

```
float a = 4.91820238;
int i;
i = a*10;
num = i/10.0;
// num has 4.9 now
```

Remember the `10.0` during the divison, if you just divide it by 10 you'll just get the integer quotient of it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an integer type and back again:

```
float myRound(float f, int num_places) {
    float factor = 1f;
    for (i = 0; i < num_places; i++) {
        factor *= 10f;
    return ((long long)(factor * (f + .5f)))/factor;
}
```

Note that the code above is subject to the usual precision/range problems regarding floating point numbers.